# Netsuite Custom GL Plugin map standard line to transaction line

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am working on a custom GL plugin for netsuite. Our setup is we have a classfication that has an income refund acct and an asset refund acct on it.

When looping through the standard lines, I need to know be able to map it to the transaction lines so that I can know if the tran item line that created this GL line's asset account and income account.

1. Is there a way to A) get the item that created the GL impact line or B) re-create somehow what the GL impact will be from a script? This way I can loop through the "what will be gl lines" and add back to an account and withdrawal from a different account.
2. Is there a way to do this with a custom column on the Credit Memo? When looping through the GL Impact I cannot access the custom column data :(

Comment: Do you have access to suiteanalytics?

Comment: Yes, I do have access to it!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to suite analytics, you can use transactionaccountingline to look at the accounting impact of each transaction.